# My procedure with cursor doesnt work

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the next procedure:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE retribAn INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 
  DECLARE cPost INTEGER(11);     
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE curTipo CURSOR FOR
          SELECT RETRIBUCION_ANUAL*1.05 AS RET_AN
          FROM EMPLEADOS  
          WHERE ID_CPOSTAL%2=0;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
  OPEN curTipo;
  REPEAT
    FETCH curTipo INTO retribAn, cPost;
    IF NOT done THEN       
      UPDATE EMPLEADOS 
      SET RETRIBUCION_ANUAL=retribAn  
      WHERE ID_CPOSTAL%cPost;  
    END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;
  CLOSE curTipo;    
END
```

when I execute it, sql manager outputs:

> Incorrect number of FETCH variables

I do not understand why.

I'm a rookie =D in mysql, and sorry for my English.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

you are selecting only one column in your cursor query and fetching data into two variables in FETCH

Try this

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE retribAn INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 
  DECLARE cPost INTEGER(11);     
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE curTipo CURSOR FOR
          SELECT RETRIBUCION_ANUAL*1.05 AS RET_AN
          FROM EMPLEADOS  
          WHERE ID_CPOSTAL%2=0;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
  OPEN curTipo;
  REPEAT
    FETCH curTipo INTO retribAn; --remove cPost here
    IF NOT done THEN       
      UPDATE EMPLEADOS 
      SET RETRIBUCION_ANUAL=retribAn  
      WHERE ID_CPOSTAL%cPost = 0;  --change this to value you want to check
    END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;
  CLOSE curTipo;    
END
```

Comment: If my answer fixed your issue, please accept it. You can check [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)  for more information about accepting and voting answers

Comment: I just join to stackoverflow, and i need 14 point of reputation, when i can vote, i will do it, dont worry. thanks again